# Frequency table for a random subset in R

Tags: r, frequency-distribution

Suppose I have a frequency chart of the ten most popular names of babies born in the US in 2006:

```
myfreq <- c(24835, 22630, 22313, 21398, 20504, 20326, 20054, 19711, 19672, 19400)
names(myfreq) <- c("Jacob", "Michael", "Joshua", "Emily", "Ethan", "Matthew", "Daniel", "Andrew", "Christopher", "Anthony")

> myfreq
      Jacob     Michael      Joshua       Emily       Ethan     Matthew      Daniel 
      24835       22630       22313       21398       20504       20326       20054 
     Andrew Christopher     Anthony 
      19711       19672       19400
```

Now consider the set of 210,843 babies with those names, born in the US in 2006. This set has 2^210843 subsets. I want the babyname-frequency chart for a **random subset** of the babies, with each subset being equally likely. My code is as follows:

```
subfreq <- sapply(myfreq, function(k) sum(rbinom(k, 1, 0.5)))
```

Is that doing what I want it to do? And is there some way to improve performance? It's going to be in a loop with millions of iterations, and the rbinom function seems very slow; I wonder if there is a faster function in R for this special case of the binomial distribution where p=1/2. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your desired output is supposed to be. I could be misinterpreting what you mean, but I also don't see why you need to use binomial draws at all, shouldn't each name's chance of being selected in a random subset of babies be its relative frequency in the whole population?

Comment: @caw5cv The desired output is a frequency table of a random subset of babies. To be clear, I'm not talking about a random subset with a given size. I'm talking about a random subset out of all the subsets of these 210,843 babies. For example, one subset is the set of 19,711 babies named Andrew. I want to ensure this subset is just as likely to be chosen as any other particular subset. But there are no subsets with (for example), 19,712 babies named Andrew. So I don't think it will work to use the R function `sample` with the probability distribution parameter.

Comment: `sum(runif(k) > 0.5)` is slightly (~40%) faster than `sum(rbinom(...))` on my machine

Comment: @Ape Thanks! I should have thought of that before. It turns out that `sum(sample(c(T,F), k, replace=T))` is even faster than using `sum(runif(k) > 0.5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done exactly. You can't construct all the possible subsets, so forget that approach.

Could be done approximately if you know some math.

First you need the probability of the sample size being `n`, which is (in `R`) naively:

```
choose(N, n)/2^N
```

That will break down for moderate `N` and `n` (for example `N=1050` and `n=525`). So you can try logarithms and after some work you get (where `lgamma` is the log of the gamma function and the gamma function at n+1 is the same as n!) the probability given by:

```
exp(lgamma(N+1) - lgamma(n+1) - lgamma(N-n+1) - N*log(2))
```

To get all the probabilities into one vector we can wrap this into a function:

```
pmf <- function(N,n) {
  exp(lgamma(N+1) - lgamma(n+1) - lgamma(N-n+1) - N*log(2))
}

N <- sum(myfreq)
probs <- sapply(0:N, function(n) pmf(N,n))
```

Note that most sample sizes have 0 probability (approximately). Now to select your sample you would first pick a sample size according to the probabilities in `probs` and then pick a sample of that size from the population of names. We need to make that population first from the frequencies you gave.

```
mypop <- rep(mynames, myfreq)
```

The sample itself:

```
sample(mypop, sample(0:N, 1, prob = probs))
```

To replicate a bunch of times:

```
k <- 100
samps <- replicate(k, sample(mypop, sample(0:N, 1, prob = probs)))
```

`samps` is a list of samples of randomly selected sizes.

Note that the only sample sizes with non-zero probabilities to be selected are:

```
range(which(probs > 0))
#> 96603 114242
```

so the properties of your samples aren't going to be as interesting as you might have thought. They will be very close to the population distribution of baby names. Definitely more interesting to have made the babies to begin with.

Comment: Ah, that clarifies things for me; I never would have figured out that wayof using the `lgamma` function to get the probability of the sample size being `n`. (Incidentally does the label `pmf` stand for something or is it arbitrary?) But this approach generates the sample itself whereas what I want is the contingency table showing the frequencies of each name. When I add in this step (using the function `table`), this approach is a bit slower than my original approach `sum(rbinom(k, 1, 0.5))`.

Comment: `pmf` is the name I gave that function, so in that sense it is arbitrary and I could have given it any name. But I chose it because the function I defined is the ***p**robability **m**ass **f**unction* for the distribution of the sample size of a randomly selected subset.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if you mean you want to simulate draws with bootstraps, but if that's what you're going for, I'd try the following approach with data.table. For a single draw:

```
library(data.table)

# Example data:
dat.namefreqs <- data.table(name=LETTERS, count=sample(1e4, size=26))

# Format:
name count
   A  7466
   B 10000
   C  8897
   D  6833
   E  8614
   F  8128
   G  1837
   H  9349
   I  7798
   J  1158
   K  1707
   L  3368
   M  1019
   N   795
   O  1840
   P  4476
   Q  5345
   R   247
   S  5430
   T  9879
   U  1328
   V  4530
   W  6865
   X  6693
   Y  2186
   Z  1754

# Total all individuals
N.tot <- sum(dat.namefreqs$count)

# Repeat each name * its frequency
dat.expanded <- dat.namefreqs[rep(1:.N, count)]

# For a single random draw,
# Create a vector of binomial draws of 1s and 0s from rbinom, size = N.tot
# Use that as a true/false vector to extract names, and aggregate counts by name

dat.expanded[which(rbinom(N.tot, 1, 0.5)==1)][, .N, by=name]
```

Example output for a single draw:

```
    name    N
 1:    A 1339
 2:    B 1851
 3:    C 2898
 4:    D 4548
 5:    E 1066
 6:    F 4421
 7:    G 4754
 8:    H 3337
 9:    I 3144
10:    J  286
11:    K 1065
12:    L  880
13:    M 3435
14:    N 1942
15:    O 3851
16:    P 2471
17:    Q 3549
18:    R 4933
19:    S 1911
20:    T 3799
21:    U 4632
22:    V 1092
23:    W 3229
24:    X  631
25:    Y 1321
26:    Z 1883
```

And for repeating through bootstrapping with foreach:
My machine runs ~1000 bootstraps in 17 seconds on a single core with the above table(136654 rows, a little over half the size yours would be)

```
library(foreach)

dat.namefreqs <- data.table(name=LETTERS, count=sample(1e4, size=26))

N.tot <- sum(dat.namefreqs$count)

dat.expanded <- dat.namefreqs[rep(1:.N, count)]

results <- foreach(n=1:1000, .combine="rbind") %do% {
    dat <- dat.expanded[which(rbinom(N.tot, 1, 0.5)==1)][, .N, by=name]
    dat[, bootstrap := n]
    return(dat[])
}

> results
       name    N bootstrap
    1:    A 1339         1
    2:    B 1851         1
    3:    C 2898         1
    4:    D 4548         1
    5:    E 1066         1
   ---
25996:    V 1055      1000
25997:    W 3234      1000
25998:    X  636      1000
25999:    Y 1315      1000
26000:    Z 1895      1000
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not trying to use bootstrapping; I was looking for, essentially, a simulation of Bernoulli sampling.